# Searching for a specific string within a mongodb database

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, cursor, mongodb-query

I have the following code:

```
collection.find({title:"foo"}, {title:1, _id:0})
```

that returns

```
{title: "foo"}
```

but when I try:

```
str = "foo";
collection.find({title:str}, {title:1, _id:0})
```

I don't get any results back.

All of the examples I've found on stackoverflow use hardcoded strings.
How can I search for a string that's constantly being changed within a mongodb database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "foo";
var query = {title: str};
collection.find(query, {title:1, _id:0})
```

Query to  find any word containing str:

```
collection.find({title : { $regex : str }}, {title:1, _id:0})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, would you also happen to know how I could find any word containing str? {title:/str/} doesn't work.

Comment: The following works: `db.collection.find({ "title" : /str/ })`

Comment: @Timmy I edited my answer to add the query for finding any word containing `str`.